# Creating an array of numbers in text in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I'm trying to code a function that creates an array with random numbers in ascending order from one to ten but in the text in the C language. So like "one", "three", "eight" etc.
This is my code so far but it is not printing the array right I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: You've added `(char)` casts which are masking the errors in your code.  Remove the casts.  Then you will see that you have declared `value` incorrectly.  It needs to be `char *value[5]`, since you want an array of character points, not an array of characters.  Or perhaps you only want a single array of characters, in which case use `strcpy`.  Also, you can't use `[5]` to index into an array of length 5.  Valid indices are 0 through 4, so you're writing past the bounds of your array, corrupting your runtime environment.

Comment: what warnings did the compiler produce?

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to your code, you still don't know well about C array and string. Like:

```
 value[5] = (char) "Zero";
```

you can't just cast a string literal to `char`.

And there is a better way to convert number to string, since you only need to handle 1..10 number:

```
const char *number_strs[11] = {
    "Zero", "One", "Two", /* and the rest */
};
// to convert 9 to "Nine"
const char *Nine = number_strs[9];
```

You may need to read carefully your C book about array and string, since I can't give you all the details here,

and good luck with C.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is:

```
char *tostring(char *value, int num){

    switch(num){
        case 0:
            strcpy(value, "Zero");
            break;
        // etc
    }
    return value;
}
```

The function now receives a pointer to an array of characters and you copy the text strings to that array. At the end you return the pointer to this array the function received.

As a summary of your errors:

- `char tostring(...` would return a single character;
- `tostring(char value[5]` is correct but I would prefer to use the pointer notation `char *value` and leave the size unmentioned;
- `value[5] = (char) "zero";` is very wrong. `value[5]` would index the array, which you don't intend to do, and the assignment does not copy the string, which you think it does.

Comment: ok this worked now I just have to figure out how to get it in ascending order.

Comment: f this helped you, then please click on the check mark to the left of my answer.